# Lost my eyes - A riddle

Tags: riddle

I saw two neighbors between my eyes.
Then I lost my right eye, but I was still the same.
Then one neighbour left, but I was still no different.
Finally, I lost my left eye and now I no longer belong to any culture.

Who was I?

Edit: Changed the wording a bit to make some points clearer

**Hint 1:**

> I come in many forms, where one form is hard to find, while a more common one might hurt you.

**Hint 2:**

> \ ( o . o ) /

Comment: Would this person say "Yarr, matey!" ?

Comment: I realized a big mistake, so I edited the riddle accordingly.

Comment: I'm thinking it's a word of the pattern `*i??i*` but I can't find one that fits.

Comment: Agree - I'm guessing the culture reference is a UK/US difference in spelling.  i.e "tranquillity/tranquility" (one neighbour can leave) or "speciality/specialty" (can remove the right 'i', not the left)

Comment: @EngineerToast If your assumption is correct, then the question will lose it's value because the questioner clearly specifies it as "eye". It may be good for verbal puzzling but not for script.

Comment: I searched for a word \*i??i\* where ?? would be 2 neighbors in the alphabet (forward and backward) but couldn't find an answer

Comment: Is there any confirmation if it's wordplay though?

Comment: hint makes me feel like it is an element of p-table.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are

> yoghourt

and your 'eyes'

> are letters 'o' rather than 'i', which commenters (including myself) tended to think

If you lose your right eye you become:

> yoghurt, the American spelling

If you lose a neighbour, you become:

> yogurt, a different spelling

However, losing your other eye makes you gibberish.

Comment: I must say I enjoyed the puzzle very much!

Comment: I never see anyone use this spelling, *but* the "culture" bit suddenly seems like a dead giveaway.

Answer (score 16):

Are you the word

> djinni?

It has two i's with two neighbors (letters) between then.  If you remove the right i you have

> the singular, djinn,

which makes sense since one "neighbor" (different than above use) left.  If you remove the left i you have

> djnni,

which isn't a word at all.

Comment: oh, this is a very good answer (I'm out of votes or I'd vote it up right now)

Comment: Nice suggestion, but this was not what I was thinking about. Also, I changed the wording of the riddle a bit.

Answer (score 7):

I saw two neighbors between my eyes.

> b**illi**ard , English word. "2 I" are eyes, "2 L" are neighbours

Then I lost my right eye, but I was still the same.

> billard  - French for billiard

Then one neighbour left, but I was still no different.

> bilard - Polish for billiard

Finally, I lost my left eye and now I no longer belong to any culture.

> blard - lost the meaning and no meaining at all in any language

Comment: This is the best answer so far.

Comment: Your last one doesn't lose the right letter, but otherwise this seems to work

Comment: thanks @question_asker i fixed it, and like you said, still this is the answer for me that fits

Answer (score 6):

Are you:

> A Jack?
>  [image]
>  The jack has two eyes with two neighboring bodies in between. If you remove one of the eyes, there is still a complete body on the other side of the card. Ditto for removing the body that lost it's eye. However, when you remove the second eye, then it is no longer a complete body.

I'm not sure how this relates to the word culture though.

Answer (score 2):

My only thought that seems to kind of fit so far is:

> Glasses/monocle.

Fitting the riddle:

> Without one lens (eye), glasses become a monocle, which is still a vision aid.  Remove the other lens, and you don't have a monocle, so you aren't *culture*d anymore.  As far as neighbors, I'm not sure.  The nose pads?

As for the hints:

> There are many types of glasses.  Monocles are hard to find.  Magnifying glasses can be dangerous... ?      :)